# Flutter message list voice record bug

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, audio

I have a chat application. Its working perfectly. I have reversed listview for show it. When i send message or photo its working so well. Sending audio is working perfectly too. But if i send audios repeatly its having strange bug.For example if i send 3 voice message repeatly and their seconds like first one is 2 seconds, second one is 5 seconds and third one is 10 seconds. Its just showing 2 seconds voices 3 times until i close and open chat detail again or until i scroll up on listview and scroll back. For make it clear some photos :

I record 9 seconds of voice and its sent and its working perfect .
[image]

After that i recording 2 seconds of voice and sending it but....
[image]

If i scroll up on listview and scroll down :

[image]

Its fixing. How can i solve it ? Thanks for help!!
This is how i put new audio to my list :

```
connection.value!.on("newMessage", (arguments) {
//Its coming from SignalR and model is coming true and inserting into my list.(GetX) (I using list reversed. )

  ChatDetailsModel model = ChatDetailsModel.fromJson(arguments![0]["data"]);
  messageList.value.insert(0, model);
  messageList.refresh();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add keys to voice widgets to help flutter distinguish them. For example:

```
MyVoiceWidget(key: ValueKey(chatMessageId));
```

Comment: man you saved my hours! Thanks its worked! I will make it correct answer after 10 minute. (I just post it thats why i cant do now.)

Comment: ok, im glad it helped. Also don't forget to add key to simple chat message widgets

Comment: i add all of them now. :)